# Map to another class with array.map()

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, stream

Consider this code:

```
class myClass {
    constructor(obj) {
        this.content = "mapped to myClass";
    }
}

array = [{content:"first"},{content:"second"}]; 
array.map(o=> {o_mapped = new myClass(); return o_mapped} ); //1*
console.log(JSON.stringify(array));

array = array.map(o=> {o_mapped = new myClass(); return o_mapped} ); //2*
console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```

I have this output, and I do not know why 2* does not work like 1*

```
[{"content":"first"},{"content":"second"}]
[{"content":"mapped to myClass"},{"content":"mapped to myClass"}]
```

Why this happens? I have used 1* version for simple manipulations with array data and it works

Comment: Start by reading the documentation: [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1):

`map` returns the new array, it doesn't manipulate the original.

*2 works because you reassign `array`, then print the new array.

If you were using `map` just to iterate and carry out side effects, like you would when using `forEach`, then you wouldn't need to reassign the array.

Answer (score 0):

map always return the new array

In this condition your are setting content and then iterating it by map function

```
    array = [{content:"first"},{content:"second"}]; 
    array.map(o=> {o_mapped = new myClass(); return o_mapped} ); //1*
    console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```

In this condition you are using default content and then iterating it by map function

```
    array = array.map(o=> {o_mapped = new myClass(); return o_mapped} ); //2*
    console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```